# Using Django's ifchanged template tag with forloop.counter

Tags: django

Django's template tags include an `{% ifchanged %}` test for use within loops to check if a value has changed. I'm using it to output a new `<div>` tag every time a variable changes.

I want every 4th `<div>` to have a specific class, but Django's `forloop.counter` variable isn't helpful here as it increments every time the loop runs, even when the `{% ifchanged %}` test doesn't run, so it outputs irregularly.

Does anyone know of a way to get around this? Obviously I can't set my own counter inside a Django view, so I have no way of checking when the 'inner' loop has changed.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby) filter:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
   ....
{% endif %}
```

### Update:

You have to use a counter+`divisibleby` filter in your template. Look at this template tag: [Counter](http://packages.python.org/django-templateaddons/template_tags/counter.html), it can help you.

Or

Filter out duplicate items (if possible) in the view before passing them to the template and use the `divisibleby` filter.

Comment: No, this doesn't do what I need - the whole problem is that `forloop.counter` is incrementing every time I iterate through the loop, whereas I only want the counter to increase when the `{% ifchanged %}` block executes.